# Cannot read JSON returned by .Net Core controller on client side

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core

In my controller I have a method that gets triggered by an `AJAX` call. I have a list of strings that I want to return

```
List<string> Usernames = new List<string>();
```

Then when data is loaded into `Usernames` I convert it into `JSON`

```
var JsonResults = Json(Usernames);
```

finally I return that `JSON` as below

```
return Json(new { success = true, resultsList =JsonResults });
```

In JavaScript, How can I loop through that array `resultsList`? Here is what the JS code looks like -

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("StartNewChat")",
    data: { SearchedText: searchedText },
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success == true) {

            // READ THROUGH result.resultsList                
        }
    }
});
```

I tried `JSON.parse()` and `result.resultsList[0]` and converting `result.resultsList` into string and back to `JSON` it didn't work.

**Edit:**
When I do a `console.log(result.resultsList)` here is what I get which is pretty strange

```
{"contentType":null,"serializerSettings":null,"statusCode":null,"value":["a","aa","aaa"]}
```

the last array is the result from `Username` array in `c#`

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you using?

Comment: its .Net Core 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `Json` method you are using, but from version 3.1 .Net Core has its own json serializer `JsonSerializer` (in `System.Text.Json` namespace) and I'm going to use that one in my answer.

As of your issue, you are serializing twice and it might not give you the `resultsList` in your final result as an array of string which you might be expecting.

Your first conversion will result in an array of strings -

```
["alice","bob","charlie"]
```

But your second conversion, depending on the serializer used, might put the entire array above inside a string and give that as the value of `resultsList` in your final result.

You should serialize once, the final object only -

```
// you need to import the following
// using System.Text.Json;

List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
names.Add("alice");
names.Add("bob");
names.Add("charlie");

return JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { success = true, resultsList = userNames });
```

It will give you `resultsList` as an array of strings -

```
{"success":true,"resultsList":["alice","bob","charlie"]}
```

Then you can loop through that array on the client end like -

```
result.resultsList.forEach(p=> console.log(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

The response has already a `JSON` so no need to parse anything.

It will be something like this:

````
$.ajax({

              url: "@Url.Action("StartNewChat")",
              data: { SearchedText: searchedText},
              type: "GET",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (result) {
                if (result.success == true)
                {
                      
                    result.resultsList.forEach( el => {
                        console.log(el)
                    })
                      
                }
            }
        });
    });
    ```
````

Comment: didnt work JS error : `result.resultsList.forEach is not a function`

Comment: I think the reason is `JSON()` in C# actually returns some other stuff too as well?!

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you have to parse the json response first try this. straight after the success line

`let result = JSON.parse(result);`

Then

```
if (result.success == true)
{                      
  result.resultsList.forEach( el => {
    console.log(el)
  })                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using by through the resultlist length.

```
          $.ajax({
          url: "@Url.Action("StartNewChat")",
          data: { SearchedText: searchedText},
          type: "GET",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (result) {
            if (result.success == true)
            {
             for (var i = 0; i <result.resultsList.length; i++) {
                   console.log(result.resultsList[i]);
               }     
            }
        }
    });
```